# reading two form elements with same name

Tags: php

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
<input type="hidden" name="fname"  value="test" />
Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

How can I read the values of both the fields named `fname`?

On my action file(test.php) under `$_POST`, I am getting only hidden field value.

Is there any PHP setting through which I can read both values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you want to name the fields as:

```
Name: <input type="text" name="fname[]" />
<input type="hidden" name="fname[]" value="test" />
```

to make PHP understand them as an Array.

Comment: Actually my purpos of posting was to know whether we have some setting in PHP.ini which would help me achieving what i wanted.... i read that their is some setting in PHP.ini... but was not clear on that... any help would be highly appreciated... Thanks for initial help...

Comment: i cann't make it array.. it dynamically generated... Can get both the values or the text field values... could this be achieved with "variables_order" in PHP.ini or some other similar setting.... Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think it depends on your needs.  If there is sometimes `1` field, and sometimes `n` fields with the same name you can still make it an Array. (Don't forget an Array can have a length of 1) ;-)

Comment: Apologies for late response... that could achievable through array no doubt in that... but what about the PHP.ini setting no help on that front?

Comment: There might be a PHP ini setting but i'm afraid I don't know.  More importantly i'm not sure what you what you are hoping to achieve?  Each parameter will have 0,1 or more values.  If you know that a field can have multiple instances, name it accordingly and loop through the values when the page is submitted.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone wants to do this and doesn't want to change the name of the form elements, or can't, there is still one way it can be done - you can parse the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] or http_get_request_body() value directly.

It would be something like

```
$vals=explode('&',http_get_request_body());
$mypost=Array();
foreach ($vals as $val) {
  list($key,$v)=explode('=',$val,2);
  $v=urldecode($v); 
  $key=urldecode($key);
  if ($mypost[$key]) $mypost[$key][]=$v;
  else $mypost[$key]=Array($v);
}
```

This way `$mypost` ends up containing everything posted as an array of things that had that name (if there was just one thing with a given name, it will be an array with only one element, accessed with `$mypost['element_name'][0]`).

For doing the same with query strings, replace `http_get_request_body()` with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Comment: To tie this in with more normal interfaces, you could make it as if you named your multiple inputs "whatever[]" by doing after the code above... `foreach ($mypost as $a=>$b) {if (count($b)>1) $_POST[$a]=$b;}` - this way you'll have $_POST operating the normal way for single elements, but as an array when there are multiple. But this would result in code mess for situations where you expect multiple elements, but the count happens to be 1 - it would need to be treated as a special case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass two form inputs with the same name, you need to make them an array. For example:

```
<input type="text" name="fname[]" />
<input type="hidden" name="fname[]" value="test" />
```

You can then access it using the following:

```
$_POST['fname'][0]
$_POST['fname'][1]
```

You might want to rethink whether you *really* need to use the same name though.

Comment: Same as @scunliffe's response ?

Comment: I actually posted it first then edited it so it looks like I posted it after. Also, he didn't mention how to actually access the values in PHP :)

Comment: Actually my purpos of posting was to know whether we have some setting in PHP.ini which would help me achieving what i wanted.... i read that their is some setting in PHP.ini... but was not clear on that... any help would be highly appreciated... Thanks for initial help...

Answer (score 0):

Solutions are

1) Try using different name for textbox and hidden value
2) Use an array as mentioned above for field name
3) Its not possible as the values will be overwritten if the names are same